# B2G - leo build error

Tags: firefox-os, b2g

I have downloaded leo code.

I am getting below error when i try to compile the source code

```
aravind.srinivas@abuild-server:~/B2G$ ./build.sh

============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=AOSP
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.0.4.0.4.0.4
TARGET_PRODUCT=full_leo
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-3.5.0-23-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-12.04-precise
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=OPENMASTER
OUT_DIR=out
============================================

>> Android tree IDs: b2g/ics_strawberry b2g/ics_strawberry-leo ics ics-leo all all-leo
>> Analyzing workspace for change...Change detected.  Applying B2G patches.
Abandon b2g_autogen_ephemeral_branch: 100% (91/91), done.
error: no project has branch b2g_autogen_ephemeral_branch
```

...
...
    [entering external/bluetooth/bluez]
      patches/all-leo/external/bluetooth/bluez/0001-Remove-OPP-L2cap-SDP-record.patch

```
[entering frameworks/base]
  patches/all-leo/frameworks/base/0001-Bug-871018-handle-OMX_StatePause-state-in-OMXNodeIns.patch
  patches/all-leo/frameworks/base/0001-Don-t-let-OMXCodec-undequeue-any-buffers.patch
  patches/all-leo/frameworks/base/OMXCodec-stop-now-waits-for-all-buffers-to-return.patch
  patches/all-leo/frameworks/base/surfaceflinger_remove_layer_alpha.patch
```

<>

...
..

```
B2G patches applied.
Blob setup script has changed, re-running
Backing up system partition to backup-leo
error: device not found
Pulling files from ../../../backup-leo
cat: ../../../backup-leo/system/build.prop: No such file or directory
Pulling "lib*ty.so"
cp: cannot stat `../../../backup-leo/system/lib/lib*ty.so': No such file or directory
Failed to pull lib*ty.so. Giving up.

> Build failed! <

Build with |./build.sh -j1| for better messages
If all else fails, use |rm -rf objdir-gecko| to clobber gecko and |rm -rf out| to clobber everything else.
```

please help me to fix this error.

Thank you.

Regards,

Aravind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect leo device for backing up system partition.
Error logs are mainly about cannot backup the file to backup-leo directory from device.

Backing up system partition to backup-leo
**error: device not found**

Comment: I have downloaded code as per guideline in MDN . step 1."git clone git://github.com/mozilla-b2g/B2G.git" step 2. cd B2G and step 3. ./config.sh leo. Now I have connected leo(d300 is the name of leo) device and start building. Within few minutes i can see the error. My device is  having FFOS up, I want source code and build it.

Comment: I doubt if d300 is same as leo device.  B2G patches applied.
Blob setup script has changed, re-running
Backing up system partition to backup-leo
error: device not found
Pulling files from ../../../backup-leo
cat: ../../../backup-leo/system/build.prop: No such file or directory
Pulling "lib*ty.so"
cp: cannot stat `../../../backup-leo/system/lib/lib*ty.so': No such file or directory
Failed to pull lib*ty.so. Giving up.

> Build failed! <
Build with |./build.sh -j1| for better messages
If all else fails, use |rm -rf objdir-gecko| to clobber gecko and |rm -rf out| to clobber everything else.

Comment: does adb work on your computer?
1. connect device to your computer
2. try "adb devices" and "adb shell"

Comment: adb works well. but i get error. As said earlier i have device similar to leo , it may not be leo device, so i may be getting error